# Mediation analysis with interaction effect

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I am currently trying to amend a paper that I am writing in order to include the interaction effects (a4 and b4 in the spreadsheet) This results in the following sum-product $$a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 + a_4b_4$$ Given that $${\Sigma (a_i \cdot b_1)=C-C'}$$ the test statistic should be the same once standardized. In theory $$ Z_{med_{AB}}= \left( \frac{a_1 \cdot b_1 + a_2 \cdot b_2 + a_3 \cdot b_3 + a_4 \cdot b_4} {\sqrt{a_1^2 \cdot SE_{b1}^2 + b_1^2 \cdot SE_{a1}^2 + a_2^2 \cdot SE_{b2}^2 + b_2^2 \cdot SE_{a2}^2 + \ldots + b_4^2 \cdot SE_{a4}^2 + a_4^2 \cdot SE_{b4}^2}} \right)$$ should equal $$ Z_{med_{C-C'}} = \left( \frac{C-C'}{\sqrt{SE_C^2+SE_{C'}^2}}\right) = \frac{-0.0297715}{0.01369}= -2.175.
$$

Unfortunately, when I try to calculate the test statistic for $\sum(a_i \cdot b_i) $ it  returned -0.54597, which is insignificant at $ \alpha = 0.05$. So the $\Sigma(a_i \cdot b_i)$ side is insignificant while the $C-C'$ side is significant. I have no clue why. Maybe the SE for the AB equation is wrong? Or maybe the variance for the AB variables is higher than the C-C' variables. But if anyone could provide insight as to what the issue is, I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, if someone could explain how to interpret the coefficient on the interaction term, I would appreciate that as well. Especially given that the component variables a2 and a3 had positive coefficients prior to adding the interaction term and as they represent % of women w/only a hs education and poverty rate and the DV is infant mortality rate, they should be positive. But the interaction effect coefficient is also much much larger than the component variable coefficients.

For what it is worth, here is the plot of the interaction effects.
[image: plot]

[image: data]

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe the SE for the AB equation is wrong?

It looks like the so-called "Sobel test", which is a first-order Taylor series approximation of the product terms sampling distributions, called the first-order [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method).  The problem with the first-order approximation is that it assumes each parameter's sampling distribution is independent of the others'.  In reality, the vector of estimated parameters have a correlated multivariate distribution.  A second-order Taylor series approximation accounts for the sampling *co*variances as well as variances.  This is called the [second-order delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Second-order_delta_method), which is still an approximation with assumptions that aren't quite tenable.  In small samples, it won't work great, but still better than what you are calculating.  It is implemented by default in `lavaan` and M*plus* for user-defined parameters.  You can also calculate it with the R package `car`, which has a generic `deltaMethod()` function.

Comment: Interesting. I also forgot that covariances can also be negative. I had assumed that because I was subtracting 2COV(C,C') that it wouldn't matter. However, I haven't the first clue how to calculate the variance for C and C'.  Apparently, monte carlo and bootstrapping is better at getting to the info I want, but in my case I simply assumed a positive covariance due to the fact that the they both have the same sign in the respective regression equations. I.e. as  input variable for C and C' increase, the output variable decreases for both.  This pos COV would reduce VAR if correct, no?

Comment: It depends on the sign of the function of the coefficients.  With inconsistent mediation, C could be bigger than C', throwing a negative sign into the mix with whatever sign your covariance is.  Anyway, with consistent mediation (C' < C, assuming both have positive sign), the indirect and direct effects tend to be negatively correlated because their sum = C.